# Scala pattern matching keep saying "match is not exhaustive!"

Tags: scala, match

I want to leverage the warning that Scala issues when a matching is missing ("not exhaustive") - so that I don't forget one (I have dozens). The following simplified example shows my attempt:

```
sealed case class MESSAGE()
class SUCCESS_MESSAGE extends MESSAGE
class FAILURE_MESSAGE extends MESSAGE

def log(str: String, msgType: MESSAGE) {
    msgType match {
        case t:SUCCESS_MESSAGE => println("FAILURE: " + str)
        case t:FAILURE_MESSAGE => println("SUCCESS: " + str)
    }
}
```

The problem is that it says "match is not exhaustive!" although all possible combinations are listed. If I'd put the "case _ =>" in there, the whole point of the warning is invalidated for me because I could add

```
class INFO_MESSAGE extends MESSAGE
```

and no warning would be issued.

Is there a solution?

Comment: SUCCESS_MESSAGE should print "FAILURE: ", are you quite sure?

Comment: I'd highly recommend against extending a case class in any circumstance.   Just FYI.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't be extending a concrete class, and especially not a case class!

Given that there's no potential to customise `SUCCESS_MESSAGE` and `FAILURE_MESSAGE`, you probably also want to make these singletons.

Finally, underscores are a Bad Thing(tm) in Scala variable or class names.  All UPPERCASE names are not idiomatic either.  So:

```
sealed trait Message
case object SuccessMessage extends Message
case object FailureMessage extends Message

def log(str: String, msgType: Message) = msgType match {
  case SuccessMessage => println("Success: " + str)
  case FailureMessage => println("Failure: " + str)
}
```

Alternatively, and I *would* recommend this, you can wrap the actual message string:

```
sealed trait Message { def msg: String }
case class Success(msg:String) extends Message
case class Failure(msg:String) extends Message

def log(msg: Message) = msg match {
  case Success(str) => println("Success: " + str)
  case Failure(str) => println("Failure: " + str)
}
```

Comment: s/in Scala variable names/in Scala class names/

Comment: variable OR class names, if you want to be exact :)

Comment: The first example still suffers the same problem, since `Message` is not marked `abstract`. The second example is ok because the abstract method `msg` guarantees that `Message` is abstract as well.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 34):

You missed one case: The message might be an instance of `MESSAGE`, not one of its subclasses.

If you want to make this case impossible, you need to make `MESSAGE` abstract. This will make the warning go away.